# In a specific mySQL row find the column with the matching value

Tags: mysql, sql, row

In my table I need to search specific columns in a specific row to find which column contains the value I define.

For example in my table

```
ID | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6
--------------------------------------------
1  | A    | B    | C    | C    | B    | A
2  | C    | B    | A    | A    | C    | B
3  | B    | A    | C    | B    | A    | C
```

I need a query to search **columns 4, 5 and 6** in **Row 2** and tell me in which column value B occurs (Col6).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a series of `CASE` conditions to match `'B'` against each column will do the job. Each must supply the string literal name of the column as its `THEN` value. You cannot dynamically determine the column names -  they must be hard-coded.

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN Col2 = 'B' THEN 'Col2' 
    WHEN Col4 = 'B' THEN 'Col4'
    WHEN Col6 = 'B' THEN 'Col6'
    ELSE 'Not found' 
  END AS which_column
FROM 
  yourtable
WHERE id = 2
```

To return more than one, you can wrap the `CASE` statements in a `CONCAT()` that returns either the column name or an empty string. This means using several separate `CASE` statements though,  instead of multiple conditions for the same case.

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    CASE WHEN col2 = 'B' THEN 'Col2 ' ELSE '' END,
    CASE WHEN col4 = 'B' THEN 'Col4 ' ELSE '' END,
    CASE WHEN col6 = 'B' THEN 'Col6' ELSE '' END
  ) AS which_columns
FROM yourtable
WHERE id = 2
```

Comment: see reference:  [CASE operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case)

Comment: This is great, thanks. Have you got any advice how to to tweak it to return more than one column name if the value appears more than once?

Comment: @JohnCatterfeld Yes, see above.

Answer (score 0):

You want the name of the column?

You could use a nested `if` e.g.

```
select if(Col4 = 'B', 'Col4', if(Col5 = 'B', 'Col5', if(Col6 = 'B', 'Col6', NULL)))
from table where ID = 2
```